# PHP Condition Setting for Button

Tags: php

[image][image]

For the first page, I want to set the column 'content control' to be button 'update or delete' because it already got data for the particular row. While for the second page, I want to set the column 'content control' to be button 'add or update or delete' as it don't have data along with the row yet. The problem I faced is how to set the first page to contain button 'update or delete' while for the second page to contain button 'add or update or delete'.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("smart_train",$conn);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM station");
  ?>
  <?php
        $i=0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $i%2==0;
        switch ($i) {
             case "0":
                 $classname="1Row";
                 $goesToPage='add_station_update1.php';
                 break;
             case "1":
                 $classname="2Row";
                 $goesToPage='add_station_update2.php';
                 break;
             case "2":
                 $classname="3Row";
                 $goesToPage='add_station_update3.php';
                 break;
             case "3":
                 $classname="4Row";
                 $goesToPage='add_station_update4.php';
                 break;
             case "4":
                 $classname="5Row";
                 $goesToPage='add_station_update5.php';
                 break;
             case "6":
                 $classname="6Row";
                 $goesToPage='add_station_update6.php';
                 break;
             case "6":
                 $classname="7Row";
                 $goesToPage='add_station_update7.php';
                 break;
             case "7":
                 $classname="8Row";
                 $goesToPage='add_station_update8.php';
                 break;
             case "8":
                 $classname="9Row";
                 $goesToPage='add_station_update9.php';
                 break;
             case "9":
                 $classname="10Row";
                 $goesToPage='add_station_update10.php';
                 break;
        }
   ?>
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $row["id"];?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row["thailand"];?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row["malaysia"];?> </td>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group" class="<?php if(isset($classname)) echo $classname;?>">
          <a href="<?php echo $goesToPage; ?>">
          <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
          </a>
          <a><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="content_control_or">or</button></a>
          <a><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button></a>
          <?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" class="<?php if(isset($addclass)) echo $addclass;?>">
          <a href="<?php echo $goesToPage; ?>">
          <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>
          </a>
          <a><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="content_control_or">or</button></a>
          <a href="<?php echo $goesToPage; ?>">
          <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
          </a>
          <a><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="content_control_or">or</button></a>
          <a><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button></a>
          <?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?>
      </div>
      <?php
        $i++;
        }
      ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Mabye offtopic but i should use MySQLi instead of MySQL

Comment: Where's your first page and second page? How do you classify a page being first page or second page?

Comment: @Rajdeen Paul I already edited my question as just now stackoverflow system block me from upload 2 photo at once

Comment: @Rickert - the MySQL extension is now deprecated.

Comment: @ajtrichards Thats why he better can use MySQLi or PDO

Comment: Out of topic question, but I curious to know that what is the difference between MySQLi or PDO and SQlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is unclear you are missing pagination display part ... but anyway with current placed code i can suggest you this simplified algorithm, with following optimizations

First of all you should create `add_station.php` and `update_station.php` files which are expect from GET `$_GET['id']` pram and then display your add or edit form fir data based on that id, we are going to use such links in html `add_station.php?id=`.$ID instead writing many `switch` and creating many duplicated `add_station_update1..10.php` files

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("smart_train",$conn);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM station");
?>

<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   ?>
  <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $row["id"];?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row["thailand"];?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row["malaysia"];?> </td>
    <td>
      <div class="btn-group" >
          <?php if(empty($row["thailand"]) && empty($row["malaysia"]) ){?>
              <a href="add_station.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
                  <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>
              </a>
          <?php }?>
          <a href="update_station.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"];?>">
              <button onclick="myFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
          </a>
          <a><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Delete</button></a>
          <?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

also my suggestion to you do not display `or` word between buttons it is anyway clear for user that he can press or on `update` or on `delete` ...

if something from above code unclear just ask

Comment: How if I wanna to make it in this way when I click the first row 'update' button, it link to update1.php while when I click the second row 'update' button, it link to update2.php and the same thing to the following row?

Comment: but why ? isn't update1.php contain form as update2.php

Comment: The reason for this because sometimes I just want to edit the first row, and I'm using different webpage to update different row

Comment: Any solution for that problem?

Comment: But from point of programming it is wrong to have duplicated files, you can achieve same first row edit functionalities with passing row id in url, E.G. if you exec url `domain.com/update.php?id=1` then in `update.php` take id from get request `$id = $_GET['id']` then you can make select `$row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM station where id=".id);` and use `$row['thailand'], $row["malaysia"]` in your <form and submit your form to save?id=.$id save php

Comment: You need to check some tutorial about that, for example i found this tutorial  which shows how to build correct `add`, `update`, `delete` forms you need to watch all 5 parts 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVHxA36l7sI , 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9ecFNkkpyA , 3:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2tQ2Zc7da0 , 4:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqGeTtQj7xs and 5:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FB_jOW6MRMQ

Comment: really thanks a lot for helping me tackle this problem, these few day I was too busy.